# Boost Asio async_send_to multicast with use_future does not work

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio, multicast

I have program that want to send a message with async_send_to to one multicast group. but I want to this action is blocking not async, so I use use_future for achieve this goal like below

```
gw::BoostMessageSender::BoostMessageSender(const std::string& group_address, const std::string& interface_name, uint16_t port_number, ba::io_context& io_context)
    : AbstractMessageSender(group_address, interface_name, port_number)
    , io_context(io_context)
    , endpoint(ba::ip::address::from_string(group_address), port_number)
    , socket(io_context, endpoint.protocol())
{
    if (!socket.is_open())
        socket.open(endpoint.protocol());

    socket.set_option(ba::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
}

bool gw::BoostMessageSender::send(const std::string& message) noexcept
{    
    std::future<std::size_t> result = socket.async_send_to(ba::buffer(message), endpoint, ba::use_future);

    return result.get() == message.size();
}
```

And I use this class like below

```
int main()
{
    const string group_address = "235.127.1.1";
    constexpr uint16_t PORT_NUMBER = 8765;

    boost::asio::io_context io_context;

    BoostMessageSender message_sender(group_address, "eth1", PORT_NUMBER, io_context);

    std::thread t1([&io_context]()
        {
            io_context.run();
        });

    this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

    message_sender.send("Any bodey there?");

    cout << "send message: "; // --- this line is not run never :(((
    
    io_context.stop();
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is why `send message` does not write in my console never?

Stranger that is, I check my network with `tcpdump -i eth0 -nnSX port 8765` and after call `async_send_to` I can see multicast message that sent to network, but `result.get()` never return result and hung on that.

Where is my wrong?

I test these code on below platforms

```
Visual Studio 2019 16.7.4
Windows 10 1909 latest update
Boost 1.73.0

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
GCC 9.3.0
Boost 1.71.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`io_context::run` returns when there is no pending jobs to be executed.

You can create *work guard* to ensure that run doesn't finish even if no async tasks were initiated. Use `make_work_guard` function:

```
boost::asio::io_context io_context;
auto workGuard = boost::asio::make_work_guard(io_context);
```

Comment: It is not possible, because send method is blocking as you can see `result.get()` so if I want to start `io_context::run` after send method, I could not do that because send method does not return eventually

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have another question, Did I can run `message_sender.send` on another thread or std::async? when I doing something like this I get exception `std::future_error: No associated state`

Comment: I add some another question about that https://stackoverflow.com/q/64063109/1539100 please see that, thanks :)

Comment: @sorosh_sabz I added the answer to that question.