# Boost Asio async_recieve_from multicast with use_future does not work simultaneously with async_send_to

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++17, boost-asio, multicast

I want to write program that send and receive multicast simultaneously like below

```
int main()
{
    const string group_address = "235.127.1.1";
    constexpr uint16_t PORT_NUMBER = 8765;

    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    auto work_guard = boost::asio::make_work_guard(io_context);

    BoostMessageSender message_sender(group_address, "eth1", PORT_NUMBER, io_context);
    BoostMessageReceiver message_receiver(group_address, "eth1", PORT_NUMBER, io_context);

    std::thread t1([&io_context]()
        {
            cout << __LINE__ << endl;
            io_context.run();
        });

    this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

    std::array<char, 20> data = {};
    auto result = std::async(std::launch::async, [&message_receiver, &data]()
        {
                message_receiver.receive(gw::buffer(data));
                cout << " receive finished" << endl; // does not reach this line :(((
        });

    this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    message_sender.send("Any body there!");

    result.wait(); // Raise exception what(): std::future_error: No associated state
    cout << "receive message: ";
    std::copy(std::begin(data),
          std::end(data),
          std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""));

    io_context.stop();
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is why result.wait() cause to raise exception?

the maybe important note that is when I remove `message_sender.send` line, this program does not raise any exception and line of `result.wait()` block until end. but when line of `message_sender.send` added, this program raise exception and does not work properly.

My message_sender is equal to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64061131/1539100) code.

And my message_receiver is like below

```
BoostMessageReceiver::BoostMessageReceiver(const std::string& group_address, const std::string& interface_name, uint16_t port_number, ba::io_context& io_context)
    : AbstractMessageReceiver(group_address, interface_name, port_number)
    , io_context(io_context)
    , listen_endpoint(ba::ip::address_v4::any(), port_number)
    , socket(io_context)
{
    socket.open(listen_endpoint.protocol());
    socket.set_option(ba::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
    socket.bind(listen_endpoint);

    // Join to multicast group
    socket.set_option(ba::ip::multicast::enable_loopback(true));
    socket.set_option(ba::ip::multicast::join_group(ba::ip::address::from_string(group_address)));
}

std::pair<bool, std::size_t> BoostMessageReceiver::receive(const AbstractMessageReceiver::MutableBuffer& buffer) noexcept
{
    ba::ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;

    std::future<std::size_t> result = socket.async_receive_from(ba::buffer(buffer.data(), buffer.size()), sender_endpoint, ba::use_future);

    return std::make_pair(result.get() != 0, result.get());
}
```

Where is my wrong?

I test these code on below platforms

```
Visual Studio 2019 16.7.4
Windows 10 1909 latest update
Boost 1.73.0

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
GCC 9.3.0
Boost 1.71.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `no_state` because `get` on `future` can be called only once.

Below

```
std::make_pair(result.get() != 0, result.get());
```

`get` is called twice.

See [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get):

> Notes The implementations are encouraged to detect the case when
> valid() is false before the call and throw a std::future_error with an
> error condition of std::future_errc::no_state.

After first call of `get`, `valid` returns `false`.